# Rename file name for spreadsheets based on table using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, file-rename, batch-rename, powershell-cmdlet

Is there a way to rename Excel documents based on content located inside it and using a data table. To be more specific, I receive a 50+ files (each with a generic, randomized name) that I must rename after the order number. I have to manually open the file to get the order number and then rename the file as such.

Is there a script I can run in Powershell, or any other tool that would help, to automate the renaming process? I have a data table containing the batch of order numbers that are contained within the folder. I was thinking that a script that would reference the table, then look within the spreadsheets to rename the file according to the order number within it would be the solution. I just don't know if it's possible, or how to write it.

Answer (score 1):

This script could be a good starting point.

1. First enumerate all `xlsx` files from some path (c:\temp in this case).
2. Open the Excel file, go to a predefined sheet `("Sheet2")` here and read the value from `Cell(1,1)`, "A1".
3. Make sure you close the workbook and the excel app.
4. Rename the file using [Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-6).

   ```
       foreach ($f in Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\" -Filter *.xlsx){

           $FilePath = $files[$i].FullName
           $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
           $wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)

           $ws = $wb.Sheets.item("Sheet2")

           $val = $ws.Cells.item(1,1).Value2

           $wb.Close()
           $Excel.Quit();

           Rename-Item -Path $FilePath -NewName $val'.xlsx'
       }
   ```